# Estimate character count in uitextview of non scrollable fixed size iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I have a scenario , where I want to calculate , How many characters can be placed within Non scrollable UITextView.

I have tried the following ,

Get the height of the Text that needs to be placed within UITextView
by the following code ,

```
CGRect rect = [labelStr boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(label.frame.size.width, MAXFLOAT)
                                         options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                      attributes:attributes
                                         context:nil];
    labelHeight = rect.size.height;
```

and also computed the height of my UITextView.

But still with these two height values , I cant figure out the way to find out the character count within my UITextView.

Any Ideas will be greatly appreciated.... 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Though not very glamorous, you could just type characters to fill the UITextView in the simulator and add a button that would count them for you, a simple method like this perhaps:

```
- (NSUInteger)numberOfCharactersInString:(NSString *)textToCheck // uitextview.text
{
    NSUInteger *numOfChars = [textToCheck length];  

    return numOfChars;
}
```

Then you'll know how many characters can fill the UITextView. But, this wouldn't be a very useful method if you're using preferred fonts that change when the user changes the Text Size in Settings.

Comment: Thanks trevorj . we just set text to the textview and users not allowed to enter text . Hence it is not posible

Comment: You could temporarily (just for testing) make it editable and add the button and method just for testing purposes and then remove them once you know how many characters the textview can handle.